# dispose() does not work in GUI as old JFrame still showing up with new Frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

This is the codding. I m trying moving from closing a JFrame to another (opening) a new JFrame in user interfaces by clicking button. But when I am close the old JFrame the new also being vanish

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        try
        {
            if(e.getSource()==btn )
        {
            dispose();
            customer s =new customer();
            s.setVisible(true);
            s.pack();
            s.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            s.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
           CloseFrame();
          
           
        }
            
            if(e.getSource()==btn1)
            {
                dispose();
                pet p =new pet();
                p.setVisible(true);
               p.pack();
                p.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                p.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
              
               
            }
            if(e.getSource()==btn2)
            {
                dispose();
                Transaction t =new Transaction();
                t.setVisible(true);
               t.pack();
                t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                t.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                CloseFrame();
                 
            }   
        
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {}        
    }
```

Comment: Your application should just have one `JFrame`.  You can use `JDialogs` to display additional information.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Answer (score 0):

is this the frame of your program? or is it a JDialog? A JDialog should have no problem with the dispose().
You can dispose your main frame this way by using `frame.dispose()`.
But only if this is your only frame. You may never use more than one frame in your GUI. JDialog is the way to go with additional windows.

I also see you try to write an Actionlistener with the `getSource()` method. I suggest you use a new class explicitly for this. then just create a `new MyListener` with the button itself.

The first line of the `MyListener` class would then be:

`public class MyListener implements ActionListener`. If you want to know about this I suggest reading on abstract classes and methods, Object oriented programming and interfaces.

Does this help you?